# How to prevent Windows from opening Start menu on shortcut CTRL+ESC in electron.js or Powershell

Tags: powershell, electron, shortcut

i'm trying to prevent Windows 10 from opening the Start Menu when an electron.js application is focused.

Right now when the electron.js app is focused and the shortcut Ctrl+Esc is pressed, the Windows menu opens.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KHqD.jpg

I'm trying to create a Powershell Script that prevent the user input when the Ctrl key is pressed but is not efficient at all, and I've been using the *globalShortcut* object from electron but when the shortcut is pressed, it does not get catched in this code

```
  app.whenReady().then(() => {
    // Register a 'Ctrl+Esc' shortcut listener.

    const ret = globalShortcut.unregister('ctrl+esc', () => {
      console.log('Control+Esc is pressed')
      return false;
    })
  
    if (!ret) {
      console.log('registration failed')
    }
  
    // Check whether a shortcut is registered.
    console.log('registered',  globalShortcut.isRegistered('ctrl+esc'))
  });
```

PD. I have use AutoHotkey for that and that worked fine, but I can not install it on every machine so I'm looking for a electron/powershell solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look to leverage PSReadLine for your use case.

> [About PSReadLine - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-7)

For example, using:

> [Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler (PSReadLine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/get-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7)

```
<#
Example 1: Bind the arrow key to a function
This command binds the up arrow key to the HistorySearchBackward function. This function searches command history for command lines that start with the current contents of the command line.
#>
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
```

To get a list of what is in there, use:

> [Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler (PSReadLine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/get-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7)

```
<#
Example 1: Get all key mappings
This command returns all key mappings, bound and unbound.
#>
Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Bound -Unbound
```